# Return multiple variables in jQuery grep function

Tags: jquery

I have an array that looks like this:

```
fields = [
  { value: "0", name: "Adam", type: "0" },
  { value: "1", name: "Brad", type: "1" },
  { value: "2", name: "John", type: "2" }
]
```

I want to grep the array to get items that match certain criteria. So I did something like this:

```js
let fields = [
  { value: "0", name: "Adam", type: "0" },
  { value: "1", name: "Brad", type: "1" },
  { value: "2", name: "John", type: "2" }
],
good = $.grep(fields, function(element) {
  return element.type == 0;
}),
bad = $.grep(fields, function(element) {
  return element.type == 1;
}),
ugly = $.grep(fields, function(element) {
  return element.type == 2;
});

console.log(good); // returns Adam
console.log(bad); // returns Brad
console.log(ugly); // returns John
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

What I would to possibly do is to avoid having to grep the array multiple times and instead grep it once. Something like this:

```js
let fields = [
  { value: "0", name: "Adam", type: "0" },
  { value: "1", name: "Brad", type: "1" },
  { value: "2", name: "John", type: "2" }
],
good,
bad,
ugly;

/* this doesn't work

$.grep(fields, function(element) {
  good = return element.type == 0;
  bad = return element.type == 1;
  ugly = return element.type == 2;
});

*/

/* this doesn't work either

$.grep(fields, function(element) {
  good = element.type == 0;
  bad = element.type == 1;
  ugly = element.type == 2;
});

*/

console.log(good); // should return Adam
console.log(bad); // should return Brad
console.log(ugly); // should return John
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to set multiple variables inside a grep function?

I also don't have any problem using something other than grep to achieve the same results in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a loop that checks the type and sets/pushes the value depending on what you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using `$.grep()` (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep).

This method filters one collection into new one, so one to one.

If you want to copy elements into three array I suggest to use built-in `Array.prototype.forEach()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or `$.each` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) to iterate over the element, switch the types and copy elements to the appropriate outputs.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `push()`.

```js
 let fields = [
      { value: "0", name: "Adam", type: "0" },
      { value: "1", name: "Brad", type: "1" },
      { value: "2", name: "John", type: "2" }
    ],
    good = [],
    bad = [],
    ugly = []
    
    $.grep(fields, function(element) {
    
    if(element.type == 0){
    good.push(element);
    }
    if(element.type == 1){
    bad.push(element);
    }
    if(element.type == 2){
    ugly.push(element);
    }
    
    });
    console.log(good); // returns Adam
    console.log(bad); // returns Brad
    console.log(ugly); // returns John
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```